# Return the largest value which is even number using a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

> ```
> def max_even_list(list):
> if len(list) == 1:
>     if list[0] % 2 == 0:
>         return list[0]
> else:
>     if list[0] % 2 == 0:
>         return max(list[0], max_even_list(list[1:]))
>     else:
>         return max_even_list(list[1:])
> ```

I'm getting an error saying: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Can anyone help me fix this code that returns the largest even number in the list

Comment: Your if returns nothing if list length is 1 and not even, if any other numbers are even then you'll be calling `max(num, None)`

Comment: Also, your indentation is off and don't use `list` for a name, it shadows the built-in list.

Comment: if that (if-else) code block is inside the function (say you forgot indentation ), then how are you calling the very function inside the definition of the function (at line 7 &9)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `len(list)` is `1` but `list[0] % 2` is not 0, you don't return anything. So this code won't work if the last element of list is odd.

What you can do is return -infinity if `len(list)` is `1` but `list[0] % 2` is not 0, as in:

```
def max_even_list(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        if list[0] % 2 == 0:
            return list[0]
        else:
            return float("-inf")
    else:
        if list[0] % 2 == 0:
            return max(list[0], max_even_list(list[1:]))
        else:
            return max_even_list(list[1:])
```

Comment: @J_lll I encourage you to review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is another way get maximum even numbers.

```
lst = [1, 2, 2 ,6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 11]

max(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, lst))
# 10
```

REF: [Python `max()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/max)

Answer (score 1):

You only need be concerned about 3 cases:

1. when the list of numbers provided is empty, return some value (in this example i picked 0. You could use `-infinity` if you want your function to support negative numbers
2. when the beginning of the list (`xs[0]`) is an even number, return the `max` of `xs[0]` and `max_even` of the remainder of the list (`xs[1:]`)
3. otherwise the beginning of the list is not even; return the `max_even` of the remainder of the list (`xs[1:]`)

This encodes into a python program with trivial effort

```
def max_even (xs):
  if not xs:
    return 0
  elif xs[0] % 2 == 0:
    return max(xs[0], max_even(xs[1:]))
  else:
    return max_even(xs[1:])

print(max_even([]))                 # 0
print(max_even([2,1,4,3]))          # 4
print(max_even([2,1,4,3,5,99,8,6])) # 8
```